# replacing values on pandas without changing the nan values as well

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I have an issue trying to replace values using np.where without changing the nan values as well.

here is the code I used but it changes the nan values as well although I don't them changed for now.

```
df["col"] = np.where(df["col"]>2, 1, 0)
```

I tried using a mask, but it didn't work as well.

```
df["col"] = np.ma.array(df["col"], mask=np.isnan(df["col"]))
df["col"] = np.where(df["col"]>2, 1, 0)
```

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `np.where` condition to keep `nan`s:

```
np.where(df["col"] > 2, 1, np.where(np.isnan(df.col), np.nan, 0))
```

Or use pandas `Series.where`:

```
df.col.where(df.col.isnull(), (df.col > 2).astype(int))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [3, np.nan, 0, 2, np.nan]})
df
   col
0  3.0
1  NaN
2  0.0
3  2.0
4  NaN

df['col'] = np.where(df["col"] > 2, 1, np.where(np.isnan(df.col), np.nan, 0))
df
   col
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  0.0
3  0.0
4  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) on column `col` to locate only the rows not `NaN` ([`.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html)) to apply the `np.where()`, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['col'].notna(), 'col'] = np.where(df.loc[df['col'].notna(), 'col']>2, 1, 0)
```

or use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and `np.where()`, as follows:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'].notna(), np.where(df["col"]>2, 1, 0))
```